# Is there an API for controlling the white tile in hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am restarting my HoloLens app , the current instance of the app is closing and new instance is starting but the white tile of previous instance is not closing , is there any way to close it?

Comment: what is a `white tile`? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I assume he means the tile as in the application seems to be still running. I think if you properly exit it will remove the tile as well.